# amcharts worldmap: rounded image marker

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

i managed to add custom marker images using this:

```
pointSeries.bullets.push(function() {
      return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
        sprite: am5.Picture.new(root, {
          templateField: "pictureSettings"
        })
      })
    })
  
 pointSeries.data.setAll([{
    geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [20.703790, 40.416775] },
    pictureSettings: {
        src: "/validators/example0.png",
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        centerX: am5.p50,
        centerY: am5.p50
      }
    }])
```

but i can't find a way to make the image rounded as a circle. I tried the "radius" property but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Would you please share the solution if you have figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is stuck, It can be done using `Container`. Check this issue on github:
https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts5/issues/1050